# Error in smooth.spline(lambda, pi0, df = smooth.df) : in qvalue package

Tags: r, statistics, q-value

I have 1493313  p values in a data frame:

```
> head(dt)
     pvals
1 0.0084956486
2 0.0012681537
3 0.0021218873
4 0.0001551133
5 0.0001894240
```

I am trying to use qvalue package to calculate True Positive Rate. (TPR)

I am doing this and getting error:

```
library(qvalue)
pvals=dt$pvals
qval_obj=qvalue(pvals) #is false discovery rate

Error in smooth.spline(lambda, pi0, df = smooth.df) : 
  missing or infinite values in inputs are not allowed
```

It this would work I would calculate TPR via:

```
pi1=1-qval_obj$pi0 #TPR
```

I don't have any NAs or infinite values there, and

```
> min(dt$pvals)
[1] 3.988883e-156
> max(dt$pvals)
[1] 0.8746981
> sapply(dt,class)
pvals 
"numeric"
```

plot of hist(dt$pvals)

[image]

I don't need to use qvalue function, if you know any other method to calculate TPR in R please let me know.

Comment: Could it be that the `pvals` column is not of an appropriate data type?

Comment: It is numeric, I will update post with that info as well. Thanks

Comment: BTW, `pi1=1-qval_obj$pi0` can't yield anything but 0 since you're setting `pi0 = 1` in the step prior.

Comment: yes that makes sense!

Comment: can you plot a histogram of the pvalues, hist(dt$pvals). Apparently if there's too many low pvalues, it will not work. (https://github.com/StoreyLab/edge/issues/13).  qvalue(runif(10000)/10) will also give you this error

Comment: I just added the histrogram to the post, indeed too many p values and qvalue(runif(10000)/10) gave me the same error. Is there is anything I can do here, use other library or?

Comment: The [`ROCS`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCS/ROCS.pdf) package comes to mind...

Comment: I am looking at the ROCS package but how do I get for my data Vector; the scores yielded by the classifier. and Vector;  the probabilistic confidence assigned by the imperfect reference stan-dard needed to run that function? In my data I have available p values, Standard Error, Beta (slope)

Comment: hey anamaria, sorry for the late reply. In this case, if you really need to calculate the fdr (or commonly called adjust p-value), I recommend using p.adjust(dt$pvals,"BH"). It assumes pi0 is zero, but in your situation, it gives you something reasonable

Comment: I am assuming the p-value is calculated correctly, because the distribution is really weird. Can you elaborate more on why you need to perform qvalue on your p-values?

Comment: Hi I did try what you said but again I got the same error: x=p.adjust(dt$pvals,"BH");qval_obj=qvalue(x);Error in smooth.spline(lambda, pi0, df = smooth.df)...

Comment: My goal is to address the tissue specificity of sharedness of eQTL gene pairs between LCLs and retina. So I found common variants between Retina and LCLs and calculated meta p value (with metap package) in between them. On that meta p value I am trying to calculate the True Positive Rate. If you know another method please let me know.

Comment: does it make any sense to log transform these p values?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, qval_obj=p.adjust(dt$pvals,"BH") and this is the adjusted p.value. You can use this as something corrected for FDR.

Comment: And, something must be wrong. You used common variants, e.g something like 1493313, and all of them are significant? This is quite impossible You need to check whether metap was run correctly

Comment: yes I did what you told me: qval_obj=p.adjust(dt$pvals,"BH") ;qval=qvalue(qval_obj); but again I got the same error about spline as in my post. They are significant because they both came from the set of significant EQTLs for two different tissues, so yes p values there would be mostly significant. I checked metap results line by line and it did a good job.